# cocos2d-iphone: init method does not work properly

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm studying Strougo/Wenderlich tutorial (space Viking project). I got troubles with chapter 4.

**In RadarDish.m:**

```
    -(void)initAnimations
        {
          [self setTransmittingAnim: [self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"transmittingAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];
        }

     -(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState {
          [self stopAllActions];
          id action = nil;
          [self setCharacterState:newState];
          switch (newState) {
          .
          .
          case kStateIdle:
          action = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:transmittingAnim
                               restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
          break;             }
          if (action != nil) {
          [self runAction:action];
                             }
}
 -(id)init
    {
    self=[super init];
     if  (self!=nil) {
    .
    .
    [self initAnimations];
    .
    .
    }
  return self;
    }
```

Exact the same code as in the tutorial. Failure:
 `*** Assertion failure in -[CCAnimate initWithAnimation:], /Users/macowner/Documents/examples/SpaceViking/SpaceViking/libs/cocos2d/CCActionInterval.`

Using debugger with breakpoints, i noticed that value of transmittingAnim = nil.

So, if i put line with

```
[self setTransmittingAnim: 
[self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"transmittingAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];
```

into case of
`-(void)changeState` then animation works correctly.

Why `[self initAnimations]` from `(id)init` is not called?
Im using cocos2d v.2 templates.
Great thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like it couldn't load the animation, check the loadplist method for any errors

Comment: if i put loading animation directly into "-(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState" it works great. Just copying lines from -(void)initAnimations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problems because I have been building project using cocos 2d v.2.0, while tutorial is based on cocos 2d templates v.1.x.x If you are going to follow the book "Learning Cocos2D", I strongly recommend you loading cocos2d-iphone version 1.0.1. Here is the link [download cocos2d 1.x.x branch](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download)

if you still want to use latest cocos2d templates, I can give you some advice:

- Follow the instructions in this link [cocos2d v2.0 migration guide](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3amigrate_to_v2.0)
- You are going to have a lot of deprecations and changes to fix, so use [this link](https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/blob/master/cocos2d/cocos2d/ccDeprecated.m)  to understand how to fix those deprecations and changes.

  Now few words about the solution of the problem I mentioned here. In each of the GameObjects, EnemyObjects, and PowerUps, I added a method to override `initWithFrameName`.

  ```
     -(id) initWithSpriteFrameName:(NSString*)frameName{
      if ((self=[super init])) {
          if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:frameName])) {

              CCLOG(@"### RadarDish initialized");
              [self initAnimations];                                   // 1
              characterHealth = 100.0f;                                // 2
              gameObjectType = kEnemyTypeRadarDish;                    // 3
              [self changeState:kStateSpawning];                       // 4

          }  
      }  
  return self;  
      }
  ```

  This allows the GameObject and GameCharacter init methods to run before the CCSprite's `initWithSpriteFrameName` method to run.
      
      The Viking GameObject had to have a slightly different solution because it is initialized with `initWithSpriteFrame` rather than `initWithSpriteFrameName`. However, the override implementation is basically the same as the example of RadarDish above.